# Angular form validation can't show multiple error message at the same time

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Here is my `<input>` tag need to be validated:

```
<input ng-minlength="0" name="name" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="name" required/>
```

And I ready two error message:

```
<small ng-show="userForm.name.$error.minlength">Too short</small>
<small ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">Required</small>
```

But when the `<input>` is empty, only the required error message showed, this situation also match the min-length error situation, how can I let the two error message both show?

Comment: First, try setting your minlength to 1 instead of 0, since you are allowing 0 characters. Second, if it's required, then is a minimum length of 1 even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You have used minlength as 0 and also used required attribute. So minimum length of 1 is necessary as commented by  @Tj Gienger .

Without the ngRequired parameter minlength parameter means that if the user has entered a value it must be at least `n` characters long, but it's ok to leave the field empty. Also you need to set the ngRequired when you use min-length.

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/620/) example(workaround) i have used minlength 5 and max length 10.

```
<input ng-minlength="5" name="name" ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="myname" ng-required="true"/>
<div ng-show="userForm.name.$error.minlength">Too short</div>                    
<div ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">Required</div>
<div ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">Too short</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already stated you would need a min length on 1.

In addition to that: Most (if not all) validators in angular (except required of course) return true if the value is empty.

See here for an example: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/validators.js#L87

So this is actually by design and there is not much you can do about this but write your own validators.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Navaneeth change your minlength to greater then 0 minlength message will only show when your criteria is not met so when the text box is empty its length would be 0 which is equal to the minlength value you have set.